# Float Object is not Callable Error in Python

Tags: python

```
degrees = float()
fahrenheit = float()
celsius = float()
meters = float()#decs.
feet = float()
selection = str()

def main():#main program
    print("Here are your choices: \n C = celsius \n M = meters \n E = exit")
    selection = input("Enter your selection")
    while selection != "e":
        if selection == "c":
            degrees(fahrenheit,celsius)
        if selection == "m":
            meters(feet,meters)
        else:
            print("Wrong input")
        selection = input("Enter your selection")
    print("Thank you for using this program")

main()

def degrees(fahrenheit,celsius):#temperature subprogram
    fahrenheit = int(input("Enter temperature in fahrenheit"))
    celsius = (5/9)*(fahrenheit) - 32
    print(fahrenheit , " degrees = " , celsius , " degrees celsius.")


def meters(feet,meters):#distance subprogram
    feet = int(input("Enter measurement in feet"))
    meter = 0.305 * feet
    print(feet , " feet = " , meter , " meters.")
```

The error appears for lines 13 and 15, the lines calling the other modules. From reading other posts, they say that using parentheses instead of * for multiplication can be the cause, but I don't see where that would be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a name conflict: `degrees` and `meters` were defined as floats and then as functions. The float names are called instead of the functions which are defined at some later point in your module.

> **floats** are not callable

---

You can resolve this by changing the name of your variables to something different. And moving the function `main` to the bottom of your module. In this way, *variable* names are distinct from function names, and the functions are already defined by the time you need to call them in your `main`.

Comment: There's also unused parameters in both functions, that are later assigned in the function body